# how can i store margin left value in a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
parseInt(slider.css('marginLeft')
```

how can i store this in a variable ?

to be like `var = parseInt(slider.css('marginLeft');`
 but it is not working

Comment: Could just be the missing `)`... Then again, you haven't named your variable, nor is `marginLeft` a valid css property, so I'm not sure where this is supposed to stand between an actual attempt and some obfuscated pseudo.

Comment: you're missing a right parenth in your post. Does that return a value in chrome console ?

Comment: `var somevar = $("#someid").css("margin-left");` in your case marginleft might be misspelled

Comment: It is not _exactly_ what he needs. There are two syntax errors: there is no variable identifier declared and there is a missing closing parentheses.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect, to assign a value to a variable, you need a variable name. Try this: var margin = parseInt(slider.css('marginLeft'));

Answer (score 0):

Assuming **slider** is some object. 
Change the following

`var = parseInt(slider.css('marginLeft');`

to

```
var marginLeft = parseInt(slider.css('marginLeft');
```